# How to get the actual download link embedded with any "Download" button

Tags: python, linux, http, python-requests, ftp

I have this code to download a big file in chunks:

```
import requests 
from tqdm import tqdm

def get_size(url):
    response = requests.head(url)
    size = int(response.headers['Content-Length'])
    return size

def download_file(url):
    local_filename = "./archive.zip"
    total_size = get_size(url) # total size in bytes
    chunk_size = 100000000 # size of 1 chunk to download 100000000 = 100 MB
    
    with requests.get(url, stream=True, allow_redirects=True) as r:
        r.raise_for_status()
        with open(local_filename, 'wb') as f:
            for chunk in tqdm(r.iter_content(chunk_size = chunk_size), total  = total_size // chunk_size): # Download a 100 mb chunk
                #if chunk: 
                f.write(chunk)
    return local_filename
```

I am trying to download [This dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/hsankesara/flickr-image-dataset) whic can be downloaded by click of a button. So I copied the link as using `copy link address` and `https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/hsankesara/flickr-image-dataset/download` the link associated with download button.

when I passed in the thhe above URL to my code, it returned that no `content-length` present means it is returning NULL. So I had to

`Download Manually in Chrome -> Cancel Download -> Go to Downloads -> Copy the link`

Which when used with `wget` or my code, easily downloaded the file.

```
!wget -O images.zip "https://storage.googleapis.com/kaggle-data-sets/31296/39911/bundle/archive.zip?X-Goog-Algorithm=GOOG4-RSA-SHA256&X-Goog-Credential=gcp-kaggle-com%40kaggle-161607.iam.gserviceaccount.com%2F20220511%2Fauto%2Fstorage%2Fgoog4_request&X-Goog-Date=20220511T155300Z&X-Goog-Expires=259199&X-Goog-SignedHeaders=host&X-Goog-Signature=aa91d1b289e42dda73637e517f85367096f2ef8b76aed372510307c3975a0b038ffe47743cf420745ff190a4a2002ff06515405571350f885d56757187d1a1be91aabe1d76a98e826a3a1396d0381ed427aa4d78c78a5131ccd9651470f5d73a9e4e915c500f4d999450b886e66a18acf650741abfb23e94d0458b628fd18f869393892004a2af9f1ddb612352c68b0287d6286acc0b89fd0e884a7adb09ab5203fed46f43e4fc9fcf865baeb8a84ca90c2d8e96bc17cd1c05a87202ba9f2e2c6127466207a334cce0a0fdff8c386b459e82dcca3b3f9452ef910a1ce42a3e0899c88a532eecf84614059808a2988ace27002f16f9134c7e69bce4848f9dc004"
```

I'm asking is that is there a way to know this link and download automatically in `requests`, `Python` or `Linux`?

Comment: Hardly. The buttons are implemented using Java Script. You would have to make your code understand the page's Java Script code. Basically you would have to implement Java Script interpreter.

Comment: The button could also be implemented using server-side scripting. This cannot be analyzed/interpreted on the client side. When I copy the link from the download button and paste it in a new browser tab, it asks me for some login, so the download operation might also depend on a session ID or cookies to decide whether it will lead you to the final download link or to an error message. And the real download link might have limited validity.

Comment: Oh! so there's no way. Thanks @MartinPrikryl

Comment: Thanks @Bodo for the  insight. I was unaware of that. It indeed take you to login page and everything else follows.